# Attempt to contain UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Can be a stupid idea, i know and i'm sorry about this but i saw this some months ago:

http://doing-it-wrong.mikeweller.com/2013/06/ios-app-architecture-and-tdd-1.html

Well, basically the idea is to not put everything (delegates, data sources, etc.) inside a `ViewController`.

I usually try to put the data source of a simple tableview in a different file in order to reuse it or simply take it easy to read and to maintain the view controller readable.

Well, it works in some cases but i'm not completely satisfied.

I **thought** a solution, imagine if we can extend a class in another file and that extension can have access to private methods and ivars, for example add a UITableView inside a UIViewController:

A standard UIViewController:

```
import UIKit

class A: UIViewController {

    private let data = ["label1", "label2", "label3"]

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Ok, now i want to use the ivar `data` to populate a `TableView`, but instead of implement the `UITableViewDataSource` methods here, i want to create an `extension` of this class that can have the access to data, something like this:

> **N.B. This is not valid in swift**

```
class A_UITableViewDataSource extend A {

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.data.count
    }

    //Etc...
}
```

Hey, look there, i can access the ivar `data` and my `ViewController` looks more readable.

Anyway this is just a small example, let me know what you guys think about this.

Have a great day, Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

All you are really doing here is making your model a VC (in a very convoluted way). In this example you would be better off making `A` a data object, creating an instance of it in your `UITableViewController` subclass and accessing the data that way (i.e. standard MVC):

```
class A : AnyObject {
    let data = ["label1", "label2", "label3"]
}
```

---

```
class A_UITableViewDataSource : UITableViewController {
    var a = A()

    // ...

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return a.data.count
    }
}
```

At least from the code you shared, this is what I can gather (and my opinion). If you think I misunderstood, shoot me a comment.

If you are concerned with structure of MVC and the size of your VC's you could always try to follow a different architectural pattern like [MVVM](http://www.raywenderlich.com/74106/mvvm-tutorial-with-reactivecocoa-part-1) or [VIPER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27442094/ios-viper-architecture-who-has-to-instantiate-a-whole-module).